# XQuery combine two xml files

Tags: xquery

Currently have two XML files and want to combine them to create 1 XML file.

XML 1 (recipes.xml):

```
<recipes>
    <recipe id="182">
        <name>Hamburger</name>
        <description>Hamburgers are created...</description>
        <chapter>1</chapter>
        <page_number>13</page_number>
    </recipe>
    <recipe id="185">
        <name>Muffins</name>
        <description>Muffins picked with...</description>
        <chapter>2</chapter>
        <page_number>43</page_number>
    </recipe>
<recipes>
```

XML 2 (ingredients.xml):

```
<ingredients>
    <ingredient id="5">
        <name>Burger Buns</name>
        <recipe_id>182</recipe_id>
        <price>$3.00</price>
        <quantity>13</quantity>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient id ="111">
        <name>Carrot</name>
        <recipe_id>182</recipe_id>
        <price>2.50</price>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient id ="535">
        <name>Blueberry</name>
        <recipe_id>185</recipe_id>
        <price>$5.00</price>
        <quantity>1 Packet of 200 grams</quantity>
    </ingredient>
<ingredients>
```

And I want them to combine to that the recipes have the ingredients like this:
Output:

```
<food>
    <recipe id ="182">
        <name>Hamburger</name>
        <description>Hamburgers are created...</description>
        <chapter>1</chapter>
        <page_number>13</page_number>
            <ingredient id ="5">
                <name>Burger Buns</name>
                <price>$3.00</price>
                <quantity>13</quantity>
            </ingredient>
            <ingredient id ="111">
                <name>Carrot</name>
                <price>$2.50</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </ingredient>
    </recipe>
    <recipe id ="185">
        <name>Muffins</name>
        <description>Muffins picked with...</description>
        <chapter>2</chapter>
        <page_number>43</page_number>
            <ingredient id ="535">
                <name>Blueberry</name>
                <price>$5.00</price>
                <quantity>1 Packet of 200 grams</quantity>
            </ingredient>
    </recipe>
</food>
```

Currently trying to do the merge in a program called BaseX. I can do simple queries using a single for loop but having troubles putting 2 separate documents together.

Comment: I am afraid neither your input samples with e.g. `<id= "182">` nor your output with e.g. `<id = "182">` is XML, you need an element name and an attribute, `<item id="182">`, so please edit your question and show us some well-formed XML samples.

Comment: Oops my bad. I see what you mean. I've edited the above post so hopefully it complies to be a well-formed XML sheet now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select the elements from the other document that match on the id and then fill them in:

```
<food>
{
    for $recipe in recipes/recipe
    let $ingredients := $doc2/ingredients/ingredient[$recipe/@id = recipe_id]
    return
        <recipe>
            {
                $recipe/(@*, *),
                $ingredients/<ingredient>{@*, * except recipe_id }</ingredient>
            }
        </recipe>
}
</food>
```

The other document you can read in as an external variable or use `doc('ingredients.xml')`, full example with external variable (defaulting for compactness of the example to inline XML) is at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2j